# Solve for the Vandermonde matrix in $V^\top a = b$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, matrix-equations

A similar question is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/384126/945612), but in my case I want to solve for the values in the [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix). That is, solve for $x_1, ..., x_n \in \mathbb{R}$ in
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & ... & 1 \\ x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & ... & x_n \\ x_1^2 & x_2^2 & x_3^2 & ... & x_n^2 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\  x_1^{n-1} & x_2^{n-1} & x_3^{n-1} & ... & x_n^{n-1}\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} a_1 \\ a_2 \\ a_3 \\ \vdots \\ a_n\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} b_1 \\ b_2 \\ b_3 \\ \vdots \\ b_n \end{pmatrix} $$
where $a_1, ..., a_n \in \mathbb{R}$ and $b_1, ..., b_n \in \mathbb{R}$ are known. In terms of algebraic geometry, it seems that I have a fixed linear combination of points on the [rational normal curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_normal_curve), and I want to solve for the points.

I want to understand when the matrix equation has a solution, and ideally how to find a solution. Really anything helps. The equation boils down to a system of polynomial equations, but I hope that the extra structure helps.

Comment: Not really. The corresponding system of polynomials is $a_1 + ... + a_n = b_1$, $a_1 x_1 + ... + a_n x_n = b_2$, ..., $a_1 x_1^{n-1} + ... + a_n x_n^{n-1} = b_n$.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I misunderstand you, but what you wrote seems to correspond to $V a = b$, whereas my question is about $V^\top a = b$. Note, for example, that in your case $a_k$ is a coefficient only for variables raised to the power $k-1$, whereas in my case $a_k$ is a coefficient for all of $1$, $x_k$, $x_k^2$, ..., $x_k^{n-1}$.

Comment: Oh, my fault. I neglected the transpose. You’re right.