# Formula for last element of zero row in symbolic gaussian elimination without swapping any rows

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, gaussian-elimination

Suppose we have an overdetermined matrix with $n$ rows and $n-1$ columns. We augment it with a column-matrix and then do Gaussian elimination on the augmented matrix. Assume that no row swapping is necessary, i.e., all pivot elements will be nonzero.

As a result of the Gaussian elimination, we obtain an upper-triangular matrix with $n$ rows and $n$ columns. Assume the last row is all-zero, except for its last element.

Is there a nice formula for expressing that last element in terms of the elements of the initial augmented matrix? In particular I'm interested in expressing it as a linear combination of the elements of the rightmost column of the initial augmented matrix.

My motivation is trying to avoid costly symbolic Gaussian elimination in a computer program, when all I want is the contents of that last element. This last element gives the constraint for the system of linear equations being consistent.

EDIT: it seems this isn't solvable as-is, but a nice formula does exist if we assume that the original unaugmented matrix is a Vandermonde matrix. Once we do a Laplace expansion on the last column of the augmented matrix, all the resulting minors are Vandermonde matrices. Vandermonde determinants are easy, so the problem is solved.

Comment: When you say "all pivot elements will be nonzero" do you mean that, during the pivoting process, given rows 1 to k-1 are finished, the entry at that time in position (k,k) happens to be nonzero? [By the way that occurring is *not* a case where no pivoting is needed, but could rather be described as "no row swaps are needed".]

Comment: Yes, I meant "no row swaps are needed", I thought that's the same thing as "no pivoting needed".

Comment: I don't think there is any way around Gaussian elimination unless the matrix is special in some way, there is no mythical shortcut out there.

Comment: @Paul does it help if the initial Nx(N-1) matrix is a Vandermonde matrix?

Comment: Dont't know sorry, but does this help https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384126/solving-linear-equations-with-vandermonde?

Comment: No I don't think determinants can help me, because I don't have a square matrix. That got me wondering: maybe the Rouche-Capelli theorem could be of help here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%E2%80%93Capelli_theorem

That theorem states that my augmented matrix needs to have rank n-1.

Comment: @enzotib the last row is treated the same as the other rows, with the goal of reducing as many elements as possible to zero.

Comment: OK, if the rank of the augmented matrix is n-1, that means the nullity (dimension of the kernel) is one. So maybe I could solve this by computing the kernel of the augmented matrix.